# SslStream asynchronous methods always return an IAsyncResult where CompletedSynchronously is True. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, asynchronous

I use TcpClient BeginConnect to create a socket connection to a TCP server.  That returns an IAsyncResult where CompletedSynchronously is false which is what I would expect at least most of the time.  I wrap the sockets NetworkStream in an SslStream call BeginAuthenticateAsClient which returns an IAsyncResult where CompletedSynchronously is true.  This really surprised me since this method makes multiple round trips to the server to do the handshake.  Every BeginWrite & BeginRead I do from that point on returns an IAsyncResult where CompletedSynchronously is true.

I suspect that the implementation of SslStream does not support async IO.  I was going to confirm this by going to the server without the SSL wrapper but unfortunately that server requires SSL so I couldn't.

If SslStream does not support async io I plan to wrap the SslStream around an in memory stream and then pass that along to NetworkStream BeginRead/BeginWrite.  Unfortunately I won't be able to do the handshake async though.

Does anybody know if SslStream in fact does not support async IO?  Is there a workaround to get it to?

Thanks.

dan

Answer (score 3):

I broke the `SslStream` apart using [Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1) and I can confirm that, at the very least, `BeginAuthenticateAsClient`, `BeginWrite`, and `BeginRead` all complete synchronously as you have observed. The callback method, however, is pushed onto the `ThreadPool` so that will come in asynchronously, but the actual read or write is already finished before `BeginWrite` or `BeginRead` return.

The odd thing about this is that it appears that `SslStream` gets everything going in asynchronous mode, but then waits for the read or write to complete before returning. Why does it do this? I have no idea!

It does not appear that there is any way to change this particular behavior of `SslStream`.

Comment: I looked at SslStream using Reflector too and while it is a fairly complicated class it does appear to do things asynchronously.  Also, I turned on .NET "Network Tracing" and I do see calls to Socket.BeginSend & Socket.BeginReceive.  Yet I am getting an IAsyncResult where CompletedSynchronously is true.  It's almost like SslStream is calling the underlying sockets async methods but then it is blocking, and waiting for them to complete.

Comment: @Dan: That is exactly what it is doing. Did you see the call to `InternalWaitForCompletion`?

Comment: But it doesn't call that, at least in CheckEnqueueHandshake, unless asyncRequest is null.  I'm going to set a breakpoint in there to see if it is ever hit.

Comment: @Dan: No, sorry. I changed gears on you. I was talking about `BeginRead` and `BeginWrite`.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalWaitForCompletion and it never hits.

Comment: It gets weirder.  I have been checking the IAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously property inside my callback and it is always true.  If I look at the property right after the Begin... call instead then it is often false and here is the really weird part calling that get_CompletedSynchronously property then causes it to return false in my callback as well.  Looking in reflector shows that the field is modified inside the property getter which is not good practice.

Comment: Hmm...yeah, the code is very complex and hard to follow. I do see what you are saying about the `LazyAsyncResult.CompletedSynchronously` property. Reflector shows that it gets modified if its value is 0. Although, it is initialized in the constructor to 1 so I'm not sure what causes it to go down that path. Still very odd indeed.

Comment: The other constructor leaves that field as 0 and that is the one SslStream calls.

Comment: Yeah, weird! Also, it looks to me like the path that leads to `InternalWaitForCompletion` does not get executed if there is already data queued up in the buffer...which I guess would mean that the read/write really did complete synchronously. But, even if `SslStream` had to request more data it looks like it would call `InternalWaitForCompletion` to me. Again, something does not seem quite right with `SslStream`. Would you agree?

Comment: Definitely.  I filed a bug in connect for this.